# AJAX response fetch additional images success not working return 200 OK

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a script that I have been using on a number of different websites without a problem now although I have an issue I can't resolve on a new site.

The hover functions below fetches additional images and inserts them after the page has finished loading.

Hover over the product pictures and inspect in firefox. 
Broken website link at: http://www.shopfashionablylate.com/handbags/shoulder-bags-and-totes

I have tried debugging this script and found that it is not reaching the success: function(json) even when I add an alert().

Comment: How ever much I try to wrap this AJAX responce in the [code] it wont work correctly.

Comment: Could the Cufon be breaking it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.shopfashionablylate.com/catalog/view/theme/CartMania-Clean/js/Futura_Std_300-Futura_Std_700.font.js"

Could Cufon be breaking it ?

Comment: It could be due to Cufon being included the 404 makes ajax think no success occured rather a failure ?

Comment: I have no idea how the cufon is being added below the HTML. I have removed all the scripts from the head.

Comment: I am guessing this is some apache/server settings that is the reason it is being added to the AJAX response.